# How to incorporate validation data in Keras's datagen.flow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

This is an extension to the problem I faced in an earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819393/how-can-i-apply-rotation-to-image-in-keras-without-using-model-fit-generator).

I am applying the following code in Keras to do data augmentation (I do not want to use `model.fit_generator` for the time being , so I loop it manually using `datagen.flow`).

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=False,
    featurewise_std_normalization=False,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# compute quantities required for featurewise normalization
# (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied)
datagen.fit(x_train)


# alternative to model.fit_generator
for e in range(epochs):
    print('Epoch', e)
    batches = 0
    for x_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32):
        model.fit(x_batch, y_batch)
        batches += 1
        if batches >= len(x_train) / 32:
            # we need to break the loop by hand because
            # the generator loops indefinitely
            break
```

I would like to incorporate the validation data into the `model.fit` loop I am running. So for instance I want to replace `model.fit(X_batch,y_batch)` with something similar to `model.fit(X_batch,y_batch, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))` within the for loop.

I am a bit confused on how to incorporate this validation component using `datagen.flow` in the for loop. Any insights are welcome on how I should proceed.

Comment: you can call model.evaluate(x_val, y_val) after fit then you get the loss and all metric values you added. see
[evaluate()](https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate)

Comment: if I do not do any data normailization , is `datagen.fit` required?

Comment: yes otherwise you don't train your model

Comment: @TobiasScheck - `datagen.fit(some_data)` pre-computes some required metrics for normalization and also for whitening. If you don't perform any of these later on, then fitting data to the data generator is not required. You can read [the docstring](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L689) for the `fit` method.

Comment: sorry my bad, i was reading model.fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have already split your data into training and validation sets. If not, you will have to do so for the following suggestion.

You can create a second data generator using the validation data, then simply [iterate over this generator at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20910242/3126298) as the training data generator. I have further help as comments in the code below.

Here is your code, altered to do this, but maybe you will want to alter a few things still:

```
# unchanged from your code
tr_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=False,
    featurewise_std_normalization=False,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# create new generator for validation
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()    # don't perform augmentation on validation data


# compute quantities required for featurewise normalization
# (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied)

tr_datagen.fit(x_train)    # can leave this out if not standardising or whitening 
val_datagen.fit(x_val)     # can leave this out if not standardising or whitening

# alternative to model.fit_generator
for e in range(epochs):
    print('Epoch', e)
    batches = 0

    # combine both generators, in python 3 using zip()
    for (x_batch, y_batch), (val_x, val_y) in zip(
                                 tr_datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32),
                                 val_datagen.flow(x_val, y_val, batch_size=32)):
        model.fit(x_batch, y_batch, validation_Data=(val_x, val_y))
        batches += 1
        if batches >= len(x_train) / 32:
            # we need to break the loop by hand because
            # the generator loops indefinitely
            break
```

Comment: great....one question.....since we have `featurewise_center=False` and `feaurewise_std_normalization=False`, can I comment out `tr_datagen..fit` and `val_datagen.fit` ?

Comment: You're welcome! My understanding from the source code (as mentioned in my comment to your question), is that we can indeed leave it out, as long as we do not perform any normalisation nor the whitening. If you need to convince yourself, try it out! Compare results of doing it and not doing it! :-) ... you may want to use a subset of data if running times are long, and set a random seed somewhere.

Comment: first of all thanks a lot for this solution. can you please add a few lines to show how to save the history of model.fit, say 'acc', 'loss', 'val_acc','val_loss', when we are training using batches.

Comment: @weber85 - saving metrics is done by including them in your model definition itself, using the `metrics` argument. E.g. model.compile(..., metrics=["accuracy"])`. Check out [the relevant documentation](https://keras.io/metrics/). If you want to save them to disk, you could use the CSVLogger: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43719666/3126298).

Comment: thanks a lot, CSVLogger is the solution I required.

Answer (score 4):

even if the post has a few months I think it could be useful: from version [2.1.5 of Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.1.5) it is possible to pass the validation_split parameter to the constructor and then select the subset when using the flow and flow_from_directory methods.

For example:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=False,
    featurewise_std_normalization=False,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2)
datagen.fit(x_train)
model = ...
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, subset='training'),
                    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data=datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, subset='validation'),
                    validation_steps=validation_steps)
```

Comment: What are good values for the steps_per_epoch and validation_steps? Also if you use the validation split, will it augment the validation data?

Comment: Since you are using data augmentation the training set is theoretically of infinite size. I typically use steps_per_epoch = len(trainining_data)/batch_size in order to have a number of samples equal to the original size of the training set.
The same applies to validation_steps whose value is set to use the entire validation set.
Unfortunately if you use the validation split the data augmentation is applied also to the validation data.